# Is there a way to manually remove WCF LOB Adapter SDK

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, wcf-lob-adapter

While BizTalk 2013 Dev edition was installed, I have updated my PC to Windows 10. Now I updated to BizTalk 2013 R2 but I cant install WCF LOB Adapter SDK because it says "Another version is already installed". I can not remove WCF LOB Adapter SDK 2013 because I can't see it in Control Panel/Remove Programs either. I tried run WCF LOB Adapter SDK 2013 msi as well but same error occurs. `msiexec /x` does not work either.

So somehow I need to remove WCF LOB Adapter SDK 2013 and install WCF LOB Adapter SDK 2013 R2 without using msiexec or control panel or I need to make windows aware of already installed WCF LOB Adapter SDK 2013 and remove it from control panel.

Answer (score 1):

if you have the installer you can just run it and choose remove, if not you'll need to download package from MS for the version of the LOB SDK that have installed, run the installer, and choose remove.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I tried to install Microsoft WCF LOB Adapter SDK with Biztalk 2016.
What I did is simple :

*1/ Performing a Silent Installation :*

**AdapterFramework.msi /quiet MUOPTIN=”Yes”** (you should be an Administrator on the computer).

MUOPTIN=”Yes”|”No” is to indicate if the WCF LOB Adapter SDK should check for updates with Microsoft Update or not.

2/ That gives you the possibilty to see The WCF LOB Adapter in Add/Remove Programs, so you can delete it and do the things correctly (install each adapter in order) or install the other adapters directly after that.

Hope it will help.